# Is there any way to modify Visual Studio to save my modified code and keep my old code as backup?

Tags: visual-studio, backup

Today I woke up to a designer error I didn't notice last time I worked on my code, and spent around an hour trying to fix it, but if I could use the version of project before the bug was created, I would probably be able to rewrite the newer changes (bugless) in half of the time.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio automatically save previous versions of my code?

Comment: Use Version Control, not Backup. Team Foundation Service or Github are the most popular choice.

Comment: You can relatively simple write your own add-in which will do it. But it is nonsense. Normally developers use versioning systems like TFS for that which you can freely get on https://www.visualstudio.com/cs/team-services/